# complicated filtering with GenericForeignKey in django

Tags: django, generics, filter

I am having a little hard time figuring this one out. I have two custom user models, (for example: Buyer, Seller) which extends a single custom user model(CustomUser) that holds all the common fields(including `email` using which we need to filter stuff) and is an `abstract` model.

Now, we are using a third party email service to send and receive email messages from/to our application. The third party service notifies us on an event. Say, if an email was bounced or failed, they will send us a POST request on a `callback` url and after authenticating the request we update our records and make note of the which email was failed.

We have an additional email model(SentMessage) where we save a message that was sent. This model looks something like this.

```
class SentMessage(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    sender = models.ForeignKey(models.InternalUser)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    recipient = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    bounced = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

As you can see, the `recipient` field in the above model is a `GenericForeignKey` and can be bound to any other model(In our case Buyer or Seller). This is the model where we'll be updating records if a message was bouced on a bounce event etc. I am looking to filter out the recipient with an email address provided by the third party service. So basically the flow would be something like.

--> Filter out the recipient using a given email address.(Where recipient can either be a Buyer or a Seller)
--> Using the above, filter `SentMessage` that was bounced or failed according to the type of event.

I am stuck at the first point here. How can i filter an object that either exists in `Buyer` model or in `Seller` model. I can't even do the following as `CustomUser` class is an abstract class, from which both `Buyer` and `Seller` inherit:

```
recipient = models.CustomUser.objects.get(email=bounced_email)
```

What would be the best way to find(filter) out `content_type`, `object_id`, `recipient` from  a given email address?

Comment: This is where you need to go https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/ First you get the class for the content_type and then get the object using object_id

Answer (score 1):

This is where you need to go https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

First you get the class for the content_type and then get the object using object_id

```
recipient = models.CustomUser.objects.get(email='guido@example.com')
messages = SentMessage.objects.filter(content_object=recipient, email=bounced_email)
```

Comment: That won't work. As i pointed out in the question `CustomUser` is an abstract class and you can't directly filter objects from it.

Comment: Sorry, forget to write down: Add a proxy to your abstract class. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-model-managers. Also, IMHO choosing an abstract model for this case is wrong.

Comment: Please specify **why** it is wrong to use abstract model for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with n3storm that an abstract model might not be ideal for this case, but I'll assume you have your reasons for using that.

In this case, perhaps a `GenericRelation` in your concrete models would do the trick, since the `GenericRelation` acts as a 'reverse relation' for a `GenericForeignKey`. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericRelation)

E.g. something like might work:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    # ... your common fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Buyer(CustomUser):
    # ... buyer-specific fields
    sent_messages = GenericRelation(SentMessage)

class Seller(CustomUser):
    # ... seller-specific fields
    sent_messages = GenericRelation(SentMessage)


recipient_list = [x for x in Buyer.objects.filter(sent_messages=bounced_email)] + 
                 [x for x in Seller.objects.filter(sent_messages=bounced_email)]
# The above list can contain at most one element since a SentMessage will reference at most one object.
```

Some remarks about validation: unless you put some validation on the `SentMessage.content_type` FK, it's not *impossible* that the GFK references another model than `Buyer` or `Seller`. This could be prevented by using `limit_choices_to` in the `content_type` FK, though you have to ensure to call the `full_clean` method of `SentMessage` model instances to apply the validation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects). The Django Admin properly uses the `limit_choices_to` to prevent entering invalid FK values.

Also, I think that by default, GFKs don't enforce the existence of the `object_id` you're referencing (at least as of 1.4, which is what I'm using). This means it might be possible to end up with a case where the `recipient_list` in the example above is empty.

**Caveat: adding a GenericRelation to a model means that deleting instances of that model will also cascade delete the GFK-linked entry.** In this case, it means that deleting a `Buyer` would delete all the `SentMessage` related to that `Buyer`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericRelation for more info on how to work around this feature/limitation.